# Buildroot multiple output directories?

Tags: cross-compiling, buildroot

Is it possible to generate multiple cross compilers with Buildroot? Without needing to transfer generated files to elsewhere before creating new cross compilers for totally different architecture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use out-of-tree compilation:

```
make O=foo foo_defconfig
make O=bar bar_defconfig
cd foo; make menuconfig; make toolchain; cd .. # builds in foo/* instead of output/*
cd bar; make menuconfig; make toolchain; cd .. # Can run in parallel
```

See section [8.5. Building out-of-tree](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#_building_out_of_tree) in the manual for more info.